# How to store javascript in app/controllers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, controller, asset-pipeline

I would like to keep Javascript controllers (Angular) next to Rails 4 controllers, in the same folder. I added this line to the config/initializers/assets.rb

```
Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'controllers')
```

And restarted server (development env), but it didn't help. Javascript files are written in Coffee and work when in standard assets/javascripts folder.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding one line in assets/javascripts/application.js

```
//= require_tree ../../controllers
```

I's because default `require_tree .` doesn't autoload all javascript files in asset pipeline, but only those in the "dot" folder of application.js, which is standard javascripts folder.

Answer (score -1):

add this line to the application.js

```
//= require_directory .
```

It will include all js files in the app/assets/javascript directory recursively